# RapidClipse Error

Tags: eclipse, html, rapidclipse

Am new to RapidClipse. I tried running it and got this error.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'test2'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RapidClipse projects are maven projects who are build with a maven plugin.
The 'Maven Project Builder' itself uses some additional plugins, among others the "maven-resources-plugin".

If a plugin doesn't exist in local repository, maven searches for it in remote repositories and tries to download it automatically to the local repository (default location: `.m2/repository` folder in user home directory).

This process fails here.

You can trigger the resolve-and-download process manually:

- Be sure there is a working internet connection and, if necessary, the proxy settings are correct.
- Rightclick on a Rapidclipse project in ProjectManagement or Project Explorer and go to `Maven` - `Update project`
- Activate the checkbox `Force Update of Snapshots/Releases` and finish the dialog with `OK`

After that, the building process for the project should work.