# RapidClipse UI Designer Error

Tags: eclipse, vaadin, rapidclipse

I am new to RapidClipse IDE as my organization requested that I study and develop with it. After having installed version 2.3.1 windows edition, I created a project but the UI designer is showing an error and the widget palette is not showing anything. Below you can find the full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.vaadin.model.DefaultBeanInfo.getDefaultValue(DefaultBeanInfo.java:676)
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.vaadin.model.Bean.getValueImpl(Bean.java:855) 
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.vaadin.model.Bean.getValue(Bean.java:829) 
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.vaadin.model.Bean.getConstraints(Bean.java:737)
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.vaadin.ui.editor.VaadinDesigner.adjustRootSizeImpl(VaadinDesigner.java:1725)
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.vaadin.ui.editor.VaadinDesigner.lambda$17(VaadinDesigner.java:1697)
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.vaadin.ui.editor.VaadinDesigner.adjustRootSize(VaadinDesigner.java:1708)
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.vaadin.ui.editor.VaadinDesigner.createUI(VaadinDesigner.java:824) 
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.vaadin.ui.editor.VaadinDesigner.loadContents_createUI(VaadinDesigner.java:764)
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.vaadin.ui.editor.VaadinDesigner.lambda$9(VaadinDesigner.java:701) 
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.core.ui.editor.multi.SwingDesignPart.invokeUIActionImpl(SwingDesignPart.java:80)
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.core.ui.editor.multi.SwingDesignPart.lambda$0(SwingDesignPart.java:69)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)j
    at ava.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at xdev.eclipse.internal.core.ui.swing.XdevEventQueue.dispatchEvent(XdevEventQueue.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(UnknownSource)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve this. Its probably a bug from the developers of RapidClipse. this is what i did:

The UI Libraries to display the designer and the pallette does not download when you create the project, so you will have to download the following:

1. xdev-server-aa
2. xdev-server-ui

from maven repository and include them in your library path. then you right click the project select maven and update project. Restart the RapidClipse IDE

Comment: Seems like an maven issue, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37990124/5027456